# Search by list of indexes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying the following code:

```
In [29]: indexes_to_search = [1, 3, 4]

In [30]: df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)], columns=["id", "val1", "val2"]).set_index("id")

In [31]: df
Out[31]: 
    val1  val2
id            
1      2     3
4      5     6
7      8     9

In [32]: df.loc[indexes_to_search]
Out[32]: 
    val1  val2
id            
1    2.0   3.0
3    NaN   NaN
4    5.0   6.0
```

For some reason, in the result it was added the index `3` with `NaN` values in columns. In my real problem `indexes_to_search` can contain non-index values (Line `3` in my example). I want to avoid add an extra line for drop the nan values sinse my DataFrame is very large.
So question is how can I search by a list of index like `.loc` without the  NaN rows.
I would expect:

```
    val1  val2
id            
1    2.0   3.0
4    5.0   6.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[df.index.intersection(indexes_to_search)]
print (df1)
   val1  val2
1     2     3
4     5     6
```

Or use `set`s intersection:

```
df1 = df.loc[set(df.index).intersection(indexes_to_search)]
print (df1)
    val1  val2
id            
1      2     3
4      5     6
```

In my version of pandas 0.22.0 get warning:

```
df1 = df.loc[indexes_to_search]
print (df1)

    val1  val2
id            
1    2.0   3.0
2    NaN   NaN
3    NaN   NaN
```

> FutureWarning:
>
> Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise **KeyError** in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative

Comment: Yes, I tried  the second option but it's really slow

Comment: OK, first should be faster.

Comment: Two options are very slow. First option is still running

Comment: @CristhianBoujon - Is possible use `df.loc[set(df.index).intersection(indexes_to_search)]` ?

Comment: Using integer indices, `Index.isin` seems to be several times faster than using sets on my machine.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko it makes sense. I my real problem I have strings as index